# Close Activity using Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

**INTRODUCTION**

I have `ActivityA` which starts a `Fragment` when I click a button. Using intent I can't start this fragment, so I've created a second activity, let's call it `ActivityB` that acts as a bridge between `ActivityA` and `Fragment`.

The structure is this : `ActivityA --> ActivityB --> Fragment`

**FUNCTIONALITY**

The functionality is from `ActivityA`, start `Fragment`, request some data, and bring this data back to `ActivityA`.

For this I use `startActivityForResult()` in `ActivityA` to call `ActivityB`. In `ActivityB` I start `Fragment` this way:

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(android.R.id.content, fragment).commit();
```

When I finish what I must do on `Fragment`, I use `setResult()` to send data back to `ActivtyA`.

**PROBLEM**

The thing is that as I have started `ActivityB` to initialize the `Fragment`, when returning the data from `Fragment` to `ActivityA`, `ActivityB` is still the one that is opened, and `ActivityA` remains on background.

This makes me not be able to process the requsted data, as the `ActivityA` which does this continues on background.

*So, what I need is to know how to close `ActivityB` when I finish operations in `Fragment`, to go back to `ActivityA` and make it visible.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method `getActivity().finish()` method in `fragment` to close `ActivityB`.

Answer (score 1):

in your Fragment, call

```
Activity activity = getActivity();
activity.setResult(...);
activity.finish();
```

when you finish operations.